# Why is NopCloser absent for io.Writer in Go?

Tags: go

Go has an [ioutil.NopCloser](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser), which is used to convert io.Reader to io.ReadCloser.
Isn't there a function that converts io.Writer to io.WriteCloser? If so, why is that?

Comment: "If so, why is that?" When was the last time you hat to convert a Writer to a WriteCloser with a dummy Close?

Comment: There could be one if one was needed, where in the std library is one needed? If you need one yourself, the implementation is quite simple.

Answer (score 8):

Only those who wrote the library could say precisely *why*, but in general, a there's an asymmetry between readers and writers: readers are not modifying anything and don't need any sort of final handshaking to stop reading.  Writers, on the other hand, often need to finalize whatever they are writing when the stream is closed.  For instance, a buffered file writer has to write out the final buffer.  A compressing writer needs to write out the final compressed block and (depending on algorithm) write a trailer.  An archive writer often needs to write a trailer as well.

Since the close of a writer is relatively rarely a no-op, while that for a reader very often is a no-op, it makes sense to provide the reader wrapper without providing the writer one.